# Propagate property changes to parents using observer pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to propogate property changes to a parent class.

For example.

Class A has a list of Class B.
Class B has a list of Class C.
Class C has a property called "IsSelected"

I want class A to be notified when  the "IsSelected" property is changed in class C.

I've spent ages googling trying to find a clear solution. Most of them include setting up events and triggers which seem like trouble down the line..

One solution I'm thinking of is to use an observer pattern where class C stores a list of observers, ie class A. Class B simply passes a reference of Class A to C for it to subscribe. When the "IsSelected" property is changed it notifies the subscribers.

This doesn't seem to be a common approach to solve this issues, so I'm hesitant in commiting to it. Are there any blatant flaws with this design that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure in this situation observer pattern has any advantages over references or events, any other pattern.

With the simple situation you describe there is nothing in the world wrong with observer or a pub/sub architectures , however there are other solution's that may fit your solution, it just depends on your design constraints

**Ideal situation for the observer pattern**

- Changes in state of an object need to be notified to a set of dependent objects, not all of them.
- Notification capability is required.
- The object sending the notification does not need to know about the receivers objects.

**You could easily justify the following solutions**

- Parent Reference passed in the constructors, or set as properties

  - Every time you create and add Class C just passing in a reference to Class A
- Delegates/events/actions

  - Every time you create and add Class C Subscribe to an event ect
- Decoupled messaging or event aggregators

  - When is selected is changed just publish to a decoupled message service or queue
- In wpf you can use triggers to raise commands in parents ViewModels

> It really depends who is making these sub classes and how/why, you
>   should be choosing the pattern which best suites the conceptual design
>   of your model; that is the most straight forward and easy to maintain
>   in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, If you want to use Observer pattern
you can set a Method in B and whenever `Isselected` Changed call `b.CisSelectedChanged();` because you have already an instance of B in your C class. And again in this method call again another method from A. Somethhign like this

```
class C
{
    bool isselected  = true;// for example get a new value , should be notified
    B b = new B();
    b.CisSelectedChanged();
}

class B
{
    public CisSelectedChanged()
    {
        A a = new a;
        a.CisSelectedChanged();
    }
}
```

this is how observer pattern works, but you need to be notified by changing the value of your property anyway